# Moment Timezone: varying (and wrong) results

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone, momentjs

I am using `moment.js` coupled with `Moment Timezone` in order to process ISO dates in different timezones. I must be doing something wrong, however, because the results I get from parsing are completely wrong, even if I to the best of my knowledge am not doing anything strange.

For example, take this date: `2015-11-23T08:56:38.646Z`

Now, a normal parse and format outputs what can be expected:

`moment("2015-11-23T08:56:38.646Z").format()`

Result: `"2015-11-23T09:56:38+01:00"`

However, if I bring a non-local TZ into the mix, things go wrong really fast:

`moment("2015-11-23T08:56:38.646Z","America/New_York").format()`

Result: `"2014-01-01T00:20:00+01:00"`

Likewise:

`moment("2015-11-23T08:56:38.646Z","Europe/Zagreb").format()`

Result: `"2015-01-17T01:00:00+01:00"`

I would very much appreciate if someone could help me understand what is going on here.

Comment: I am an idiot - of course this does not work. The correct invocation should be `moment.tz()`, not simply `moment()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is trivial and was due to a careless mistake on my part. I am leaving it here for the benefit of any scarce person who may do the same thing.

The correct way to use timezone conversion is to call `moment.tz()` rather than just `moment`. Hence, for example:

`moment("2015-11-23T08:56:38.646Z","America/New_York").format()`

should be

`moment.tz("2015-11-23T08:56:38.646Z","America/New_York").format()`